# How to encode a search query with javascript

Tags: javascript

If I search for How to Format i get

> How%20to%20Format

but I want to be **How-to-Format**

```
window.location = '/search/'+encodeURIComponent(query);
```

also escape(), encodeURI() dont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
window.location = '/search/'+ query.replace(/\s+/gi, '-');
```

Working example with stripping multi-spaces into one:

- http://jsfiddle.net/VVEpE/

Answer (score 1):

`encodeURIComponent` (and the broken, deprecated `escape`) will convert space characters to representations of a space that you can put in a URI.

If you want to use custom slug generation rules then you will have to write them yourself, probably using a regular expression.

e.g.

```
query.replace(/\s/g, "-");
```

Answer (score 0):

[`string.replace(searchvalue,newvalue)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

in this case

`window.location = '/search/'+query.replace(/ /g, '-')`

Comment: this will replace only the first match of the `' '`, not every space!